# Apache server port forwarde not working outside the network

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have an apache server running on Ubuntu 16.04 and which works fine with http://localIP:8082 and http://publicIP:8082 inside the network. But when I try from outside the network the link not working. I have correctly forwarded the port 8082 and in https://canyouseeme.org/ I can see the port 8082 is open. I have checked the apache server status and no error found. What could be the reason.

Edit:

In apache access.log, I can see the request log is logged

```
237.197.106.261 - - [10/Dec/2019:03:49:42 -0500] "GET /DB_123/checkAlive.php HTTP/1.1" 200 320 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"
```

So the request reaching the server, but no respond  for the request. what could be the problem.

Comment: Check a firewall and routing configuration. Try capturing traffic with `tcpdump` to investigate whether there are packets reach your server, there are answers to these packets and so on.

Comment: Is it due to configuration problem in apache server, or it could be firewall problem.